# PL\SQL expected from error

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a following query. I just want to take current year and month, then use this information in following query. What would be the error reason?

```
declare 
KATSAYI3=to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') from dual;
KATSAYI4=to_char(sysdate, 'MM') from dual;
KATSAYI5=to_char(CONCAT(KATSAYI3,KATSAYI4));
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Inner Variable num1: ' || KATSAYI5);
END;

select * from DQ_TES_DATA where YEARMONTH=KATSAYI5;

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:

. ( ) , * % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)>
and or || multiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few errors in PL/SQL block:

- types of variables are not declared
- an assign operator `:=` must be used instead of `=`
- `from dual` is needless

This should compile and run:

```
declare 
  KATSAYI3 varchar2(100) := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
  KATSAYI4 varchar2(100) := to_char(sysdate, 'MM');
  KATSAYI5 varchar2(100) := to_char(CONCAT(KATSAYI3,KATSAYI4));
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Inner Variable num1: ' || KATSAYI5);
END;
/
```

---

Another issue - variable`KATSAYI5` is local in the above block, it is visible only in this blok, you can't use it in the query.

You can use substitution variables, more on the here: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia

Try this code:

```
variable xx varchar2

declare 
  KATSAYI3 varchar2(100) := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY');
  KATSAYI4 varchar2(100) := to_char(sysdate, 'MM');
  KATSAYI5 varchar2(100) := to_char(CONCAT(KATSAYI3,KATSAYI4));
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Inner Variable num1: ' || KATSAYI5);
  :xx := KATSAYI5;
END;
/

select * from DQ_TES_DATA where YEARMONTH=:xx;
```

`variable xx varchar2` in ths code is a substitution variable which is global within the session, and can be used in the query.

Comment: Hi kordirko,
Thanks for answer. However, The result of query above is null. Records doesn't appear. Why it could be?

Comment: There is no data in the table that matches the generated value of :xx?